MongoDB createIndex compound unique index on array field
I'm trying to create a unique index in MongoDB that enforces uniqueness based on the existence and non-undefined nature of a field (barcodes) in my skus collection. Here's the index creation query I'm using:
db.skus.createIndex({ tenant_id: 1, seller_id: 1, barcodes: 1 }, { unique: true, name: "tenant_seller_seller_sku_code_barcode_1", partialFilterExpression: { barcodes: { $exists: true } } })


MongoServerError[DuplicateKey]: Index build failed: 796ad1b8-4527-47dd-8cd8-8b498e29099f: Collection product_service_db.skus ( 1cfaec4d-475e-42d7-ae23-6183651f2203 ) :: caused by :: E11000 duplicate key error collection: product_service_db.skus index: tenant_seller_seller_sku_code_barcode_1 dup key: { tenant_id: "1", seller_id: "133", barcodes: undefined }

db.skus.createIndex(
  {
    tenant_id: 1,
    seller_id: 1,
    barcodes: 1
  },
  {
    unique: true,
    name: "tenant_seller_seller_sku_code_barcode_1",
    partialFilterExpression: {
      barcodes: { $exists: true, $ne: undefined }
    }
  }
)


MongoServerError[BadValue]: Error in specification { unique: true, name: "tenant_seller_seller_sku_code_barcode_1", partialFilterExpression: { barcodes: { $exists: true, $ne: undefined } }, key: { tenant_id: 1, seller_id: 1, barcodes: 1 } } :: caused by :: unknown operator: $ne

It seems MongoDB doesn't recognize $ne: undefined in the partialFilterExpression. How can I correctly specify the condition to create a unique index based on the existence and non-undefined nature of the barcodes field?
Collection Sample
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "tenant_id": "1",
  "seller_id": "133",
  "barcodes": ["barcode1", "barcode2"]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "tenant_id": "1",
  "seller_id": "134",
  "barcodes": null
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "tenant_id": "2",
  "seller_id": "135"
}



See Create a Partial Index

The partialFilterExpression option accepts a document that specifies
the filter condition using:

equality expressions (i.e. field: value or using the $eq operator),
$exists: true expression,
$gt, $gte, $lt, $lte expressions,
$type expressions,
$and operator,
$or operator,
$in operator


I think $type should work:
partialFilterExpression: {
   barcodes: { 
      $exists: true, 
      $type: [ "string", "null", "array" ]
   }
}    

Be aware to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564
